# When is the Amazon S3 lifecycle rule executed?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have configured the Amazon S3 buckets (just some special ones) with a Lifecycle Rule to run every 1 day to move the bucket objects to Glacier.

I have checked the buckets many times but I'm not seeing it executed. The docs I referred to are [Object Lifecycle Management - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/object-lifecycle-mgmt.html).

However, I can't find any places to show the executed time.

Also read through [Working with Amazon S3 Buckets - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingBucket.html)

Any ideas are really appreciated.

Comment: I've heard that it can take up to 48 hours to execute the Lifecycle Rule. How long has it been since the rule and objects were created?

Comment: Also, you should enable logging on your buckets and observe the logs.  Transitions aren't instantaneous and if you have a large number of objects, the logs are a good way to determine whether transitions have started.

Comment: Thanks @JohnRotenstein and Michael for the comments. It's working now. I saw the buckets moved to Glacier. So, It happened around 24 hrs or a little more with my case. Thanks again.

Answer (score 16):

According to this
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-lifecycle-rule-intelligent-tiering/

```
Lifecycle rules run once a day at midnight Universal Coordinated Time (UTC).
```

Comment: Your link does not contain the quote. This link does https://aws.amazon.com/de/blogs/aws-cloud-financial-management/discovering-and-deleting-incomplete-multipart-uploads-to-lower-amazon-s3-costs/

Answer (score 3):

Found the answer in the official AWS S3 documentation (which was more helpful/trustworthy for my case since tech like Intelligent-Tiering keeps changing).

Transitioning an object to another storage class (such as S3 Intelligent-Tiering) takes until at least midnight UTC.

[AWS Lifecycle documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/intro-lifecycle-rules.html):

> Amazon S3 calculates the time [a `Transition` or `Expiration` Lifecycle action should occur] by adding the number of days specified in the rule to the object creation time and rounding the resulting time to the next day midnight UTC. For example, if an object was created at 1/15/2014 10:30 AM UTC and you specify 3 days in a transition rule, then the transition date of the object would be calculated as 1/19/2014 00:00 UTC.

[AWS Intelligent Tiering documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/using-intelligent-tiering.html) - This describes a Lifecycle which transitions objects to S3 Intelligent-Tiering after 0 days:

> The rule specifies a Transition action directing Amazon S3 to transition objects to the S3 Intelligent-Tiering storage class 0 days after creation. In this case, objects are eligible for transition to S3 Intelligent-Tiering at midnight UTC following creation.